# android O kills service; what condition resulted into this?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on making an app compatible with android-o & I noticed that the system is doing something new with a one of my services in this android version.

The situation:

- `class MyService extends Service { .. }` is started together with an activity
- `MyService.onStartCommand(..)` returns `START_NOT_STICKY`
- after user leaves all screens an alarm is is scheduled to be executed a minute later

The new logic I'm experiencing is that `MyService` gets constantly stopped when the minute-later-alarm starts ringing. Service is consistently stopped immediately before `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(..)` is called by the ringing alarm. Also it doesn't seem to matter whether the alarm is set to ring after 60 or 70 secs.

Android O is the only OS version (of the ones i tried) that is doing this. What is the logic here? Can i stop this without returning `START_STICKY`?

Answer (score 4):

There are new limitations for background services in Android O.

Check out the doc: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#services

Use `JobScheduler` and `JobService` instead.

More info on how to use that: https://medium.com/@cwdoh/jobintentservice-for-background-processing-on-android-o-39535460e060